# Firebase query function returning undefined when page is refreshed

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I Got a service in Angular that gets User Data from firestore. The relevant service code is as follows:

```
userType:string = ''

async getProfileType(): Promise<string> {
    const userUID = await this.getUserUID();

    const getUserType = () => {
      this.af
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userUID)
        .valueChanges()
        .subscribe((doc: any) => {
          console.log(doc.userType);
          this.userType = doc.userType;
        });

      return this.userType;
    };
    return getUserType();
  }
```

When I try to invoke it in the component by injecting it and calling the function in the ngOnInit method I get the following error:
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userType')`

And when I invoke the function from the service manually it returns the data fine, but I'm not sure why it can't do the same thing when invoked on the ngOnInit method.

I've tried making ngOnInit async and use await on the getProfileType function but that didn't seem to make a difference.

The Component TypeScript is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { UserInfoService } from '../services/user-info/user-info.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-profiles',
  templateUrl: './edit-profiles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-profiles.component.scss'],
})
export class EditProfilesComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public userInfo: UserInfoService, private af: AngularFirestore) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.userInfo.getProfileType();
  }
```

The Component HTML is as follows:

```
<div *ngIf="userInfo.userType === 'user'">
  You're a User
</div>
<div *ngIf="userInfo.userType === 'project'">
  You're a Project
</div>
<button mat-flat-button (click)="userInfo.getProfileType()">Get Profile Type</button>
```

Any help or direction is appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getProfileType` method claims to be returning a `Promise<string>`, but it's actually just returning a `string` that hasn't been initialize yet as you're never awaiting the database result.

```
async getProfileType(): Promise<string> {
```

I'd recommend returning an `Observable<string>`, since the profile type may change:

```
getProfileType(): Observable<string> {
  const userUID = await this.getUserUID();

  return this.af
    .collection('users')
    .doc(userUID)
    .valueChanges()
    .pipe(map((doc: any) => {
      return doc.userType;
    }));
}
```

Alternatively, you can stick to the `Promise` approach, but then return just one document with `take(1)` or `first()`:

```
getProfileType(): Observable<string> {
  const userUID = await this.getUserUID();

  return this.af
    .collection('users')
    .doc(userUID)
    .valueChanges()
    .pipe(take(1))
    .pipe((doc: any) => {
      return doc.userType;
    });
}
```

Comment: Would I have to unwrap the observable to then use it for conditional rendering?  b/c that was the whole point of the function to be able to conditionally render based on data from the back-end. The first function given doesn't return anything to my knowledge when I tested it & logged it. Is there anything else I can try?